# How to create dynamic menu in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a navigation menu using jQuery, in that what I want to do is to change the whole menu according to the item I clicked, The menu is in upper navigation bar

eg;

**Update**     (currently first item)
**Review**  -> clicked on this
**MyReview**
*changes to:*
**Review**    (become first item)
**MyReview**
**Update**

Mean to say want to create a cyclic menu, and for that I have to change the id of menu items also I am using this for reference, but not getting how can I change this code for my use.

[Dynamic menu items (change text on click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916403/dynamic-menu-items-change-text-on-click)

My Code is :

```
<script>
$(function(){
var menuList = [ "Update", "ReviewQueue", "MyReviewQueue"];
var m_length = menuList.length;

$("#menu ul li").click(function () { 
     //$('#menu ul li.active').removeClass('active');
     //$(this).addClass('active');
     $('.goMenu', this).text(this.id);

     $("#menu ul li").not(this).each(function(i) {
         $('.goMenu', this).text(menuList[i % m_length]);
     });
});
});
</script>


<title>My Review Queue</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a id="Update" class="goMenu" href="#">Update</a>
<ul>
<li><a id="ReviewQueue" class="goMenu" href="#">Review    Queue</a></li>
<li><a id="MyreviewQueue" class="goMenu" href="#">My review Queue</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6zMqU/3/

Comment: fiddle not working error at $('.goMenu', this).id(this.id);

Comment: fiddle working now, but not getting the desired result

Comment: tried using innerhtml in jquery at http://jsfiddle.net/6zMqU/7/ but still problem is there as innerhtml tags are not identified during runtime, only while clicking at MyReviewQueue link it is getting reordered but not further

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li class="main-menu">
    <a id="Update" class="goMenu" href="#">Update</a>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a id="ReviewQueue" class="goMenu" href="#" data-menu="review">Review    Queue</a>
     </li>
    <li>
        <a id="MyreviewQueue" class="goMenu" href="#">My review Queue</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="hide review">
    <a href="#">Review Queue</a>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>

$(function(){
    $('.goMenu').on('click', function(e){
        $('.main-menu').addClass('hide');
        $this = $(e.currentTarget);

        clasz = $this.data('menu');

        $( '.' + clasz ).removeClass( 'hide');
    });
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6zMqU/